# WHM / cPanel : Manage Wheel Group Users and SSK Keys access

Tags: shell, ssh, cpanel, whm

I want to disable direct root logins to my server, which runs WHM with Centos 6.5 and add specific user to the wheel group in order to be able to perform tasks with root privileges.

I've done the following - while logged in via ssh as root, I've created new user:

```
newuser newsuperuser
```

and I've set the password for it

```
passwd newuserpassword
```

I then went ahead and added that user to the wheelgroup, by going to:

```
Security Center > Manage Wheel Group Users
```

and added `newsuperuser` to it.

I then went to:

```
Security Center > Manage root's SSH Keys
```

and generated new key with `newpassword` - then authorised it.

Next I've copied the private key to my local (Mac OSX) .ssh directory, run chmod 600 and added file to ssh session:

```
ssh-add newsuperuser_key
```

typed password when prompted.

Now if I try to connect to the server via ssh using:

```
ssh newsuperuser@800.800.800.800
```

(using the correct IP address :) - I get:

```
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've done everything right, but in order to make it work you need a few extra steps. Full instructions can be found here: [SSH with Root Login disabled](http://www.ssdtutorials.com/tutorials/title/ssh-root-login-disabled.html).

Once you've created the additional user, you need to copy the authorized_keys to your new user's root directory and the .ssh directory within it, which you'll have to add manually:

```
cp /root/authorized_keys /home/newsshuser/.ssh/
```

Then change the ownership of the newly copied file:

```
chown newsshuser:newsshuser authorized_keys
```

Edit `sshd_config` file:

```
nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

and uncomment and set:

```
PermitRootLogin no
```

Restart the ssh:

```
/etc/init.d/sshd restart
```

Logout and log in with new username.

Comment: Hi. This does not seem to work when user has a custom home directory like /var/svn-depot

Comment: Did you try to create the .ssh directory inside of that custom /var/svn-depot one? Give it a try and copy the `authorized_keys` file there as described above.